# Update PyQt progress bar from a different script

Tags: python, pyqt

I have a progress bar and I would like to update the progress easily. I imagine something like this. One script is generic and describe the progress bar. And the other will be updating it.

```
from progress_bar import Ui_Dialog
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtWidgets
import time

app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
Dialog = QtWidgets.QDialog()
ui = Ui_Dialog()

ui.setupUi(Dialog)
Dialog.show()

ui.set_min_max(0,200)
for i in range(1, 201):
    ui.setProgress(i)
    time.sleep(0.1)

sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

And the progress bar description :

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtWidgets



class Ui_Dialog(object):
    def setupUi(self, Dialog):
        Dialog.setObjectName("Dialog")
        Dialog.resize(400, 133)
        self.progressBar = QtWidgets.QProgressBar(Dialog)
        self.progressBar.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(20, 10, 361, 23))
        self.progressBar.setProperty("value", 24)
        self.progressBar.setObjectName("progressBar")
        self.pushButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(Dialog)
        self.pushButton.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(20, 40, 361, 61))
        self.pushButton.setObjectName("pushButton")

        self.retranslateUi(Dialog)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(Dialog)

        self.progressBar.minimum = 1
        self.progressBar.maximum = 100

    def retranslateUi(self, Dialog):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        Dialog.setWindowTitle(_translate("Dialog", "Dialog"))
        self.pushButton.setText(_translate("Dialog", "PushButton"))
        self.progressBar.setValue(0)


    def setProgress(self, value):
        self.progressBar.setValue(value)

    def set_min_max(self,mini,maxi):
        self.progressBar.minimum = mini
        self.progressBar.maximum = maxi
```

Is there a way to launch the progress bar to an other thread and update it  from the original script ?

Comment: Your code has many errors, besides that it seems that you do not know the difference between classes and objects. Another thing I do not understand is this command: `self.pushButton.clicked.connect (self.setProgress)`, what do you intend to do with that command?

Comment: edit to be more consistent.

Comment: What you are trying in your code doesn't work. What you need is threading. [This example](https://nikolak.com/pyqt-threading-tutorial/) may be of help to you.